# Laptop doesnt go past POST

Tags: overheating, dell-latitude, post

My laptop that is a Dell E6410 and I was working on it when it kinda got un responsive. So I force shut down it.
Now it won't go past a black screen after POST. I can get into BIOS and tried resetting it manually i.e. via removing the cell from the laptop and the battery too, and also via the bios itself. But still the same. BTW when on black screen the heat vent heats up like hell.
I'm out of ideas so any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Specs:
DELL E6410
Core i7-720QM
6GB DDR3-1066
dGPU NVidia NVS3100m
Kingston SSDNOW300 240GB
OS: Deepin 15.2 (Ubuntu based)

If I missed something relevant mention it in the comments and I'll add.

Comment: Does it just stick at a blank screen or does it restart itself? Are you able to try another hard drive to see what might happen?

Comment: You should tag your question with Linux OS and Ubuntu. Obviously it's not your only computer. Can you download a "Repair Disk" for Linux OS systems?

Comment: It stays there and doesnt do anything. I can try that other hdd option. As for the ubuntu thing. That isnt it coz the hdd light doesnt show activity.

Comment: Forgot to add one thing in my comment. Can't boot to a usb too. Same happens. A blank screen.

Comment: I reset the bios for the 100th time and it started to work. It showed a line intel media firmware etc line for a second and it booted! Now is anyone able to tell me why it didnt work before?

Answer (score 0):

The computer that you used to post to this website, I would try using a usb stick and see if you can boot to Ubuntu with that on your computer stick. At least you can confirm a working and non working computer, and a working and non working bootable flash drive.

When your computer did boot finally, was it just after you updated your firmware? If not how long was your computer off before you attempted to try again, I am thinking overheating or firmware issues? That is just my 2 cents worth.

Comment: I was using my phone for posting on the site btw. I did try to boot it from usb it didnt do anything but give the same black screen. I was giving it a try after like 2 hours. First I booted it up it gave the black screen, then I got in to bios and restored defaults and booted it again and it worked. I had done the same steps before and it didn't work. But I am with you on over heating. It was damn hot like 40/45 C when this happened, could that mess up the bios?